# How to get only the name of the path with python?

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
a = "/home/user/Downloads/repo/test.txt"
```

My goal is just to create a string which contains only `test`, how can I do this ?

actually `a` comes from

```
f = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
```

and `a` is equal to `a = f.name`

but I realized `f.name` does not give me just the name of the file.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the final part *without* the extension?

Comment: Hint: look in module `os.path`

Comment: `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(a))[0]`

Comment: Ignore all of those old answers for python 2.x on the question from 2009. Use pathlib.

Answer (score 334):

In Python 3.4+, you can use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module (included in Python's standard library):

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path("/home/user/Downloads/repo/test.txt")
>>> print(p.stem)
test
>>> print(p.name)
test.txt
```

Comment: is there a way to get the stem and its extension?
**EDIT**: looked in the documentation, the answer is `p.name`

Comment: Won't work if there's multiple extensions e.g. test.original.txt.

Comment: For the else who looking for: you can get the parent directory via: `p.parent` and suffixes (extensions) via `p.suffixes`

Comment: Unfortunately, `p.parent` does not yield a `Path` so it breaks the chain. :/

Comment: @Raphael It does. Are you using Python's native pathlib or some other package?

Comment: Huh. Good that you ping me; I had some code yesterday where I got `PurePosixPath` where I didn't expect it, but now I'm getting `PosixPath` and can simplify my code. Weird. Anyway, thanks for remote-rubber-ducking! :D (And yes, vanilla 3.7 `pathlib`.)

Answer (score 17):

Use the [`os.path` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) to work with paths; the [`os.path.basename()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) gives you the last part after the last path separator, and [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) gives you the filename with the extension split off:

```
import os.path

basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f.name))[0]
```

Using the `os.path` functions ensures that your code will continue to work correctly on different operating systems, even if the path separators are different.

In Python 3.4 or newer (or as a [separate backport install](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/)), you can also use the [`pathlib` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which offers a more object-oriented approach to path handling. `pathlib.Path()` objects have a [`.stem` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem), which is the final component without the extension suffix:

```
try:
    import pathlib
except ImportError:
    # older Python version, import the backport instead
    import pathlib2 as pathlib

basename = pathlib.Path(f.name).stem
```

Demo:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> a = "/home/user/Downloads/repo/test.txt"
>>> os.path.basename(a)
'test.txt'
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(a))
('test', '.txt')
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(a))[0]
'test'
>>> import pathlib
>>> pathlib.Path(a)
PosixPath('/home/user/Downloads/repo/test.txt')
>>> pathlib.Path(a).stem
'test'
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're either looking for `os.path.basename` or `os.path.splitext`:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.basename("/var/log/err.log")
'err.log'
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename("/var/log/err.log"))
('err', '.log')
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename("/var/log/err.log"))[0]
'err'
>>>
```